# Problem in getting multidimensional array from simple xml object

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

As a newbie I need your help in getting multidimensional array from simplexml object.
 suppose my array is like:
just for getting idea:
Here $data is a simplexml object contains below xml:

```
<users>
  <user>
    <id></id>
    <nm></nm>
    <gender>
      <male></male>
      <female></female>
    </gender>
  </user>
</users>
```

Here I an perfectly getting array of each user, but in that array when it comes to gender, it shows nothing. i need array of gender too. I am using following code:

```
foreach($data->users as $users)
{
  $arr1 = array();
  foreach($users as $user)
  {
    foreach($user as $k=>$v)
    {
      $arr1[$k] = (string) $v;
    }
  }
  $arr2[] = $arr1;
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please cleanup question -- it is very hard to see what you're talking about. "suppose array is like: just for getting idea:"? Also, putting the code on their own lines, and formatted, will greatly help.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the foreach iterator correctly. It should be something like this:

```
$users = simplexml_load_string($the_xml_thing_you_posted);

foreach ($users->user as $user)
{
    $arr[] = array(
        'id' => (string) $user->id,
        'nm' => (string) $user->nm
    );
}
```

Now I have no idea what you're trying to do with your gender thing, both elements are empty, what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

`foreach($user as $k=>$v)` doesn't iterate over all the child elements in your `user` element. It iterates over all `user` elements that are children of `$users`. For illustration:

```
$data = new SimpleXMLElement('<data>
  <users id="1">
    <user id="user1a"></user>
    <user id="user1b"></user>
  </users>
  <users id="2">
    <user id="user2a"></user>
    <user id="user2b"></user>
  </users>
</data>');

foreach($data->users as $users)
{
  echo 'users id: ', $users['id'], "\n";
  foreach($users as $user)
  {
    echo "  user id: ", $user['id'], "\n";
  }
}
```

prints

```
users id: 1
  user id: user1a
  user id: user1b
users id: 2
  user id: user2a
  user id: user2b
```

You probably want something more like

```
$data = new SimpleXMLElement('<data>
  <users>
    <user>
      <propA>A1</propA>
      <propB>B1</propB>
      <propC>C1</propC>
    </user>
    <user>
      <propA>A2</propA>
      <propB>B2</propB>
      <propC>C2</propC>
    </user>
  </users>
</data>');

$result = array();
foreach($data->users as $users)
{
  foreach($users as $user)
  {
    $arr = array();
    foreach($user->children() as $e) {
      $arr[$e->getName()] = (string)$e;
    }
    $result[] = $arr;
  }
}

print_r($result);
```

which prints

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [propA] => A1
            [propB] => B1
            [propC] => C1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [propA] => A2
            [propB] => B2
            [propC] => C2
        )

)
```